# Overlapping Div Sections, can't figure out why

Tags: html, css, row

I am trying to create a contact section at the bottom of my bootstrap website, with a col-md-3 containing a picture, and col-md-9 beside it carrying the infomation

Except when i make the window smaller the text begins to overlap the picture instead of sitting under or beside it

I have tried making the image responsive, and looking at other ways of keeping it alongside but i cant figure out the issue.

Im sure i am missing something really simple, an would greatly aapprecite any help

I have searched this website for overlapping div issues, and tried a few things but nothing seems to work

```
<section class="contact bg-grey" id="contact">
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="contact-header">Contact Me:</h2>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">


            <img src="img/me.png" class="responsive" id="bio">

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9" id="contact_details">
                <h3 class="contact-header">John Gillespie</h3>
                <p>Email: johngillespiexxx@gmail.com</p>
                <p>Phone: 07xxxxxxxxx</p>
                <p>Twitter: @jxhngillespie</p>
            </div>
        </div>



      </div>
    </section>
```

I was expecting when the page size shrinks that the image would shrink with it, or that the text would stay along side, until the screen becomes too small and then fall underneath. Instead of this happening the text begins to overlap the image

Answer (score 0):

If you add `style="max-width: 100%"` to the `img`, it will prevent the image from overflowing outside of its column (the `100%` is relative to the width of the column). By default, images always display at their full resolution unless you constrain them in this kind of way.